# How to print all variables along with their values of a function without calling them by name?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know that it is possible to for `objects` to reference themself using `self`.
So if want to `print` all the `variables` along with their `values` assosiated with an object I can do something like this:

```
class print_class:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var1 = 1
        self.var2 = 2
        self.var3 = 3

    def display(self):
        var = self.__dict__
        print(var)

>>> pc = print_class()
>>> pc.display()
>>> {'var1': 1, 'var2': 2, 'var3': 3}
```

I am wondering if it is possible with python `functions`.

Suppose I defined a function like this:

```
def print_fun():
    var1 = 1
    var2 = 2
    var3 = 3
    var  = some_function(which is what I want) 
    print(var)

>>> print_fun()
```

Is it `possible` to `print` all of it's `variables` along with `values`(without calling explicitly their name)?

(I think it is possible because it is python :) and everything even functions are instances of `PyObject` and everything is `live`)
If possible `how` can we achieve that?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#module-inspect

Comment: `locals()` maybe what you want

Comment: To get the locally scoped variable names, you can use `print_fun.__code__.co_varnames`. See [Python Scope and LEGB Rule](https://realpython.com/python-scope-legb-rule/#functions-the-local-scope)

Comment: @Joran Beasley  thanks thats what I want

Comment: Note that a [debugger](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) might be what you actually want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the built-in function [`locals`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) to get a dictionary of names and values of local variables:

```
var = locals()
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `inspect`, you can write a function to display data from whatever function it is called from.

```
import inspect

def print_fctn_vars():
    frame = inspect.currentframe().f_back
    print(frame.f_locals)
```